# How to build an Arduino sketch that just controls the ESP32's built-in LED on/off with MQTT?

Tags: arduino, mqtt

Minimal Node-RED Flow:

```
[{"id":"54a41959.4635b8","type":"ui_switch","z":"a7f8495b.bfc4c8","name":"","label":"Manual control","tooltip":"","group":"bd744462.1dd638","order":1,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"","style":"","onvalue":"1","onvalueType":"str","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"0","offvalueType":"str","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":220,"y":140,"wires":[["2ea19dd1.d00062"]]},{"id":"2ea19dd1.d00062","type":"rbe","z":"a7f8495b.bfc4c8","name":"Update if state changed","func":"rbe","gap":"","start":"","inout":"out","property":"payload","x":450,"y":140,"wires":[["f2ea955c.9f7c18"]]},{"id":"f2ea955c.9f7c18","type":"mqtt out","z":"a7f8495b.bfc4c8","name":"MQTT Out","topic":"test1","qos":"","retain":"","broker":"34a0d767.dc2698","x":670,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"bd744462.1dd638","type":"ui_group","name":"Default","tab":"ffeb5903.9edf68","order":2,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"34a0d767.dc2698","type":"mqtt-broker","name":"","broker":"localhost","port":"1883","clientid":"","usetls":false,"compatmode":false,"keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthPayload":"","closeTopic":"","closeQos":"0","closePayload":"","willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willPayload":""},{"id":"ffeb5903.9edf68","type":"ui_tab","name":"Home","icon":"dashboard","disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

I tried BROKER_IP with my IP address and just with "localhost." Neither worked:

```
    /*
     * esp32_secrets.h file (saved with Arduino sketch)
     * Note, NETWORK_NAME and PASSWORD are replaced with their real names.
     * 
    */
    #define SECRET_SSID  "NETWORK_NAME"
    #define SECRET_PASS  "PASSWORD"
    #define BROKER_USERNAME  ""
    #define BROKER_PASSWORD  ""
    #define BROKER_IP  "localhost"  // https://whatismyip.com
    #define CLIENT_NAME  "ESP32_client_1"
    #define BROKER_PORT  1883
```

The [MQTTBox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mqttbox/kaajoficamnjijhkeomgfljpicifbkaf/q) shows 0 and 1 when the switch is toggled. So it is publishing. I can provide details on how to replicate this if needed or you can trust my word ;)

```
/*
 * .ino sketch
 * 
*/

#include "EspMQTTClient.h"
#include "esp32_secrets.h"

const byte bluLEDpin = 2;

String light_control_topic = "test1";

EspMQTTClient client(
  SECRET_SSID,
  SECRET_PASS,
  BROKER_IP,        // MQTT Broker server ip
  BROKER_USERNAME,  // Can be omitted if not needed
  BROKER_PASSWORD,  // Can be omitted if not needed
  CLIENT_NAME,      // Client name that uniquely identify your device
  BROKER_PORT       // The MQTT port, default to 1883. this line can be omitted
);


//----------------------------ONCE---------------------------- 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(bluLEDpin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(10);


}


//----------------------------LOOP---------------------------- 
void loop()
{
  client.loop(); // must be called once per loop.

}


void onConnectionEstablished()
{
  client.subscribe(light_control_topic, [](const String & bluLED_state){
    light_control(bluLED_state);
  });
}


void light_control(String bluLED_state)
{
  Serial.println(bluLED_state);
  
  if (bluLED_state[0] == '0')
  {
    Serial.println("On");
    digitalWrite(bluLEDpin, LOW);
  }
  else if (bluLED_state[0] == '1')
  {
    Serial.println("Off");
    digitalWrite(bluLEDpin, HIGH);
  }    

}
```

I get no output on the Serial Monitor, and the LED does not go on. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? I suspect an issue might be naming `BROKER_IP` in the .h file.

Comment: I've removed the node-red tag, since the messages are arriving at the broker (as seen in MQTTBox) so this has nothing to do with the publishing side.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `localhost` or the value returned by whatismyip.com are going to work as the broker address.

`localhost` always points to the machine actually executing the code in question, which in this case is going to be the Arduino it's self. For more details read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

The address from whatismyip.com is going to be the external IP address of your router as assigned by your ISP which unless you have set up port forwarding is not going to point to the machine with the broker running on it. (You should not be setting up port forwarding unless you really understand what you are doing).

You need to know what the LAN IP address of the machine with the broker is. In most cases this will be in one of the [rfc1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) ranges. Most probably starting with `192.168.`

Without knowing what OS you are running on that machine it is hard to suggest what to run, but probably something like `ip a`, `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` will shows you what you need.

Comment: These are the only ones I get from the Command Prompt: Link-local IPv6 Address = fe80::6d26:7aa3:dbf8:d34%5 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .IPv4 Address = 10.0.0.209

Comment: Then the address is `10.0.0.209`, I did say most likely to be a `192.168` but the rfc1918 lists all the private ranges

Comment: Then you need to look at any firewall on the machine and that what ever broker you are using is configured to listen on more than just localhost

Comment: Windows Defender Firewall. Should I allow "Wireless Portable Devices" or?

Comment: Probably, but I don't do Windows so you'll have to try